How to avoid duplicate event publications with Spring Modulith's Event Externalization
I'm using Spring Modulith's event externalization feature, which offers at least once delivery. However, how can I minimize duplicate publications?
For example, if I configure the application to republish messages on startup, can I indicate which instance of the app should do this? Alternatively, can I use the database lock to make sure only one instance retrieves the events for republishing?
I was wondering if anything like this is provided out of the box.

You might be interested in my blog post about this: https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2024/06/25/transactional-outbox-pattern-with-spring-boot/
